Reload viewpoint in orthographic mode
I'm trying to  reload some saved viewpoints in the viewer and I'm encountering an strange behavior when trying to load viewpoints created in ortho mode. Basically I do not get the correct zoom.
Below is the screenshot taken at the moment that I saved the viewpoint :
viewpoint screenshot 
An then, when I load this viewpoint in the viewer I get this :
viewer after loading the viewpoint
So in this case, I get something with less zoom. If I zoom in, I get the correct view.
Everything works fine for viewpoints in perspectives cameras.
What I'm missing here ?

When you say "saved viewpoints", are you referring to saving and restoring the viewer state using the getState and restoreState methods? I've tested this functionality now using the following steps, and it's working fine:

go to https://aps-simple-viewer-nodejs.autodesk.io/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cGV0cmJyb3otc2FtcGxlcy9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0
set some custom camera position, direction, and zoom level
in the console, store the viewer state using state = NOP_VIEWER.getState()
change the camera randomly
in the console, restore the viewer state using NOP_VIEWER.restoreState(state)
the camera is restored properly

Have you perhaps customized your viewer app in some way that could interfere with the viewer state saving/restoring?
